# get 2 decimal numbers with auto round off

Tags: jquery

How to get 2 decimal numbers with auto round off to my auto total amount fields `.val()` function in jQuery.

heres my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#AmountPaid, #OtherCharges, #Amount').on('input',function() {
        var AmountPaid = parseFloat($('#AmountPaid').val()).toFixed(2);
        var OtherCharges = parseFloat($('#OtherCharges').val()).toFixed(2);
        var Amount =   $('#Amount').val(parseFloat(AmountPaid) + parseFloat(OtherCharges));

    });
});
</script>
```

I have

> AmountPaid = 63.48 
>  OtherCharges= 10 
>  Amount =
>   73.4799999999999

total should be = 73.48

Comment: why you don't use toFixed() again? Is any issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this trick: multiply the number by 100 and then use javascript's `round` to get it to an interger, then divide by 100.

```
var Amount =   $('#Amount').val(Math.round((parseFloat(AmountPaid) + parseFloat(OtherCharges)) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Hi receive `Uncaught ReferenceError: round is not defined`

Comment: Sorry. Need `Math.round`.

Comment: Hi it works but, there are some errors on console. `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val(...).toFixed is not a function` & `The specified value "NaN" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?
6panelco1_form:351 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val(...).toFixed is not a function(anonymous function) @ panelco1_form:351dispatch @ jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3i @ jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3`

Comment: You may not need the `toFixed(2)`.